# Why does IO.DirectoryInfo.FullName break when a path ends with "\CON"?

Tags: c#, vb.net

I'm using IO.DirectoryInfo to sanitize a path. However, it seems to exhibit strange behaviour when a path ends with "\CON". For example:

```
IO.DirectoryInfo("C:\FOOBAR\").FullName
```

Will return:

```
C:\FOOBAR\
```

However, in these examples:

```
IO.DirectoryInfo("C:\CON").FullName
IO.DirectoryInfo("C:\SUB\CON").FullName
IO.DirectoryInfo("..\CON").FullName
IO.DirectoryInfo("CON").FullName
```

The return value is always:

```
\\.\CON
```

So, when the user wants to create a directory called "CON", the whole program blows up.

Of all the weird things I've seen the .Net Framework do in the past, this takes the cake. Can anyone explain what's going on here?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

CON is a reserved file name, with a long history as an MS-DOS device name. As is stated in documentation on naming files, paths and namespaces:

> **Do not use the following reserved names for the name of a file:**
>   CON, PRN, AUX, NUL, COM1, COM2, COM3, COM4, COM5, COM6, COM7, COM8, COM9, LPT1, LPT2, LPT3, LPT4, LPT5, LPT6, LPT7, LPT8, and LPT9. Also avoid these names followed immediately by an extension; for example, NUL.txt is not recommended.

Refer to https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa365247%28v=vs.85%29.aspx

Comment: Thanks for clearing that up.

So, NTFS/FAT32 not only has a list of reserved characters for file/directory names, but also a list of reserved strings. I can use System.IO.Path.GetInvalidFileNameChars() and System.IO.Path.GetInvalidPathChars() to check for reserved characters. I guess the next obvious question is how one would best check for these invalid names and inform the user of their error more gracefully.

This appears to be poorly handled at the OS level too. I can run "mkdir CON\" from a command prompt. The directory gets created but there's no way to cd into it. Ugh.

Comment: Wow! Save me from a Monday full of panic and pain!!!

Answer (score 3):

I suspect it's because `CON` is a holdover from DOS.  In DOS `CON` is a special file referring to the CONSOLE, so you can do this in a cmd prompt:

```
COPY CON FILENAME
```

1. Now type whatever you want in the file named FILENAME, i.e. "here is some sample text."
2. Terminate with a DOS end of file (Control-Z).

You now have typed directly into the file named FILENAME from the CON(sole).  To view what you typed, type `type FILENAME`.  You'll see whatever you typed.

But for this to work there has to be a special file named `CON` always available in the system--it's sort of like an alias to STDIN--and I suspect that .NET will not allow you to put CON in the path of a folder for that reason.

Comment: Wow. That's an interesting hack. I've always just piped an "echo" command to a file to do that. I guess this way would allow carriage returns.

Comment: Yeah, it's a fun bit of ancient history.